# Stringfy rapidjson trigger random segmentation fault

Tags: c++, string, rapidjson

My code is to convert a json document into string:

```
class JMSG_C: public rapidjson::Document
{
  inline std::string JMSG_C::get_msg_str()
  {
    // Convert JSON document to string
    rapidjson::StringBuffer buffer;
    rapidjson::Writer< rapidjson::StringBuffer > writer(buffer);
    Accept(writer);
    std::string str = buffer.GetString();
    return str;
  }
}
```

Function get_msg_str() fails on segmentation fault. The error message is as in the following. The error does not happen every time but randomly. I suspects that is due to memory allocation failure. But when the program runs, I monitor the system RAM consumption and don't see RAM exhausted. Anybody has any idea?

```
*** Process received signal ***
Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
Failing at address: 0x96a5e64d
[ 0] [0xb770d40c]
[ 1] /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(+0x7129e) [0xb732b29e]
[ 2] /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(+0x73565) [0xb732d565]
[ 3] /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(__libc_malloc+0x5c) [0xb732fa6c]
[ 4] /home/logia/work/projects/dev_Tao/products/mpitao/mpitao(_ZN9rapidjson12CrtAllocator6MallocEj+0x11) [0x809a7e5]
[ 5] /home/logia/work/projects/dev_Tao/products/mpitao/mpitao(_ZN9rapidjson19MemoryPoolAllocatorINS_12CrtAllocatorEE8AddChunkEj+0x1e) [0x80a4bf6]
[ 6] /home/logia/work/projects/dev_Tao/products/mpitao/mpitao(_ZN9rapidjson19MemoryPoolAllocatorINS_12CrtAllocatorEEC2EjPS1_+0x74) [0x80a2c6a]
[ 7] /home/logia/work/projects/dev_Tao/products/mpitao/mpitao(_ZN9rapidjson8internal5StackINS_19MemoryPoolAllocatorINS_12CrtAllocatorEEEEC2EPS4_j+0x9e) 

[ 8] /home/logia/work/projects/dev_Tao/products/mpitao/mpitao(_ZN9rapidjson6WriterINS_19GenericStringBufferINS_4UTF8IcEENS_12CrtAllocatorEEES3_NS_19MemoryPoolAllocatorIS4_EEEC2ERS5_PS7_j+0x2d) [0x809f255]
[ 9] /home/logia/work/projects/dev_Tao/products/mpitao/mpitao(_ZN6JMSG_C11get_msg_strEb+0x64) [0x809ad50]
[10] /home/logia/work/projects/dev_Tao/products/mpitao/mpitao(_Z9cell_mainR6COMM_C+0x7da) [0x80aba23]
[11] /home/logia/work/projects/dev_Tao/products/mpitao/mpitao(main+0xef)

[12] /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xe6)
```

Comment: why are you inheriting from Document??

Comment: because I simply want to expand rapidjson::Document class

Comment: I cannot notice obvious problem. Is it possible to make a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: @user2494308 and why would you want that, you are just making this simple task difficult for you.

Comment: I only pasted the relevent part of JMSG_C class. There are many other feature implemented in JMSG_C, which stands for "json message class". Essentially I plan to encapsulate a json document into a message that is used for communication between different SW entities.

Comment: @user2494308 I still don't get it why you need this for achieving your task.